# cisco vpn automatically disconnecting

Tags: cisco-vpn-client

I am having some problem with my vpn client. My cisco vpn automatically disconnects. I don't know why. It is saying Connection VPN connection terminated locally by the client. Reason 422.Lost contact with the security gateway. Check your network connection.

Answer (score 2):

Check that the remote system and local host system are not using the same IP subnet.  I have seen this cause the client to drop

Answer (score 1):

A VPN can disconnect for a number of reasons:

- when the VPN disconnects, do you still have internet connection?
- can you still ping the endpoint (the remote gateway) on both DNS name and IP?
- is the VPN idle? Some VPN connections tend to disconnect when being idle and rebuild when there is activity again on the VPN connection.
- Is there an idle time-out of some sort configured?

These are just suggestions since the information that is given is not much.